# Can't install graphics driver on Wheezy - Using Inspiron 3537

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, graphics-card, debian-wheezy

I've recently installed Debian Wheezy 7.5 and dual booted it with Ubuntu 14.04.
I've installed all of the drivers except the graphics driver which I've been trying to install for a couple of days.
When I first booted Wheezy I got an error message that said "GNOME 3 Failed to Load" . The GUI was loading fine but pretty basic, so I knew that this is a graphics driver issue.
I ran `lspci | grep VGA` and got this:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`
I then ran `lspci | grep Display` and got this:

`03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6660`

I tried installing the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package but it didn't configure my graphics driver. 
My Ubuntu loads the graphics driver fine.
Is there any recommendations for the package I could install, and if I need to do any modifications to xorg.conf so I can load GNOME 3?
Could I copy the graphcis driver configurations from Ubuntu to Debian Wheezy?
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 3537 - Core i5 processor
My Kernel version is `3.14-0.bpo.1-amd64`

Comment: Hi, I have mostly the same problem with my asus laptop "Integrated Intel® HD Graphics" videocard; I am really stuck with this issue cause it seems there is no debian device driver manager or else; All intel's installers https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=13815 are dedicated for ubuntu and fedora only :( so If you found out some workaround please share it

Comment: I'm currently stuck with the same problem. Debian wheezy ships with the xserver-xorg-video-intel package in version 2.19 but 2.20 is required for the integrated Haswell graphics. Backporting doesn't seem to be trivial, you can build the package from jessie but for me 3d acceleration is still broken afterwards.